# Docker desktop can't switch to linux container

Tags: windows, docker, windows-10, virtual-machine

When I try to switch windows container to linux container it gives following error.

```
Unable to create - The running command stopped because the preference variable "ErrorActionPreference" or common parameter is set to Stop: The operation failed.



   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.<TrySendAsync>d__5.MoveNext()

--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---

   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()

   at Docker.Core.Pipe.NamedPipeClient.Send(String action, Object[] parameters)

   at Docker.Actions.<>c__DisplayClass36_0.<SwitchDaemon>b__0()

   at Docker.ApiServices.TaskQueuing.TaskQueue.<>c__DisplayClass17_0.<.ctor>b__1()
```

Comment: Device manager --> Network Adapters --> delete all the Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapters.
Restart the docker and it will automatically create an Hyper-V Virtual Ethernet Adapters. Keep an eyes on the device manager and make sure there is only one Hyper-V adapter.
https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/429#issuecomment-327880634

Comment: I have deleted all adapters.... And restarted the docker... But still issue is there... Also it didn't create any adapter by itself.

Comment: Hi @AbhishekParmar were you able to resolve this ? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @Rahul Still I'm having this issue

Comment: @AbhishekParmar thanks for your response. I am now using docker version [2.1.0.5](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/release-notes/#docker-desktop-community-2105) and it is working fine for me.

Comment: @Rahul I already have 2.1.0.5 but no luck...